# asp.net web application template is missing visual studio 2017

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I have visual studio 2017 enterprise edition but asp.net web application template is missing. I have asp.net core 2 installed on my machine.

[image]

[image]

[image]

here are the installed components

[image]

It was there but dont know how they got removed.

Please suggest me how can i see web application template and asp.net mvc templates?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to run the Visual Studio Installer and check all installed options, or trying a repair

Comment: please have a look at updated question, thanks

Comment: From the main installer window click More and then repair to try and repair your installation

Answer (score 3):

After you select a project type of Web Project then click OK you will be taken to a dialogue which will allow you to select the web project type:

**For .Net Framework:**

[image]

**For .Net Core:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue in Visual Studio 2019 and upgrading / repair did not work. However, there is `dotnet new` that is very easy to use and requires less time than trying to fix VS templates. Example:

- default project creation (preview)

  ```
  dotnet new mvc --dry-run
  ```
- help related to various options such as authentication (None, Individual etc.)

  ```
  dotnet new mvc --help
  ```